# How to write a Dropbox file (through their API) using StreamWriter in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, dropbox-api, streamwriter

I've been fighting against the Dropbox API and I've made my little steps (I'm new on C#). The thing is that I've finally reached a file on my Dropbox account but I don't know how to create it on my local machine through StreamWriter.

Note: I know the await thing and so on could be easily improved, but I'm still getting into it :'D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dropbox.Api;

namespace Try1Dropbox
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ApiKey = "$$longChickenToken%%!!xD";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = Task.Run(async () => await Program.Run());
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                var inner = ex.InnerException;
                Console.WriteLine(inner.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static async Task Run()
        {
            using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(ApiKey))
            {
                var full = await dbx.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
                await ListRootFolder(dbx);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", full.Name.DisplayName, full.Email);
                Console.ReadKey();
                await Download(dbx, @"/", "remotefile.pdf");
            }
        }

        private static async Task ListRootFolder(DropboxClient dbx)
        {
            var list = await dbx.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);

            // Show folders,  then files
            foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFolder))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("D  {0}/", item.Name);
            }
            foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F{0,8} {1}", item.AsFile.Size, item.Name);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, file);
            var args = new Dropbox.Api.Files.DownloadArg(path);
            using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(args))
            {
                using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\prueba\localtest.pdf"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());
                    sw.Write(response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync());

                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point goes to sw.Write, where I "try to insert" the response I get on console but I just get this "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Byte[]]" instead.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the n00bance. New on C# and Dropbox API.

Comment: WriteLine is printing the String representation of the Task object returned. Split that call into `var response = await response...` and then print whatever Property of it you want printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written the following:

```
sw.Write(response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync());
```

Anyway, the signature of the method is

```
Task<byte[]> GetContentAsByteArrayAsync()
```

Hence, you are passing a `Task<byte[]>` to `sw.Write(...)`. The default behavior of `StreamWriter.Write` - for an object passed - is to [write the text representation of an object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dfc2b8zk(v=vs.110).aspx) - which is the type name for many classes - this is what you've seen. Furthermore you did forget to `await` the async operation, hence you've got a `Task<byte[]>`. You'll have to `await` the call in order to obtain the actual `byte[]` and not the `Task<byte[]>`. See the call to `GetContentAsStringAsync`.

Since you'd like to write an array of `byte`s here, you don't need a `StreamWriter`, but can operate on *raw* (well not exactly, but more raw than a `StreamWriter`) streams.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\prueba\localtest.pdf"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());

    var dataToWrite = await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
    stream.Write(dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.Length);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Dropbox API docs, the `GetContentAsStringAsync()` method being `async` returns `Task<string>`. `Console.Writeline` will simply call `Task<string>.ToString()` and what you see is the default implementation of the `ToString()` method.
What you want to write is the actual result:

```
var taskResult = await response.GetContentAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(taskResult.Result);
```

You caN find more information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a solution!

```
private static async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, file);
    var args = new Dropbox.Api.Files.DownloadArg(path);
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(args))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\prueba\localfile.pdf"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await response.GetContentAsStringAsync());
            var bytes = await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
            await sw.BaseStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, the ToString magic wasn't all that magic XD Thanks guys!

Comment: Please see my answer: You did forget the `await` and passed a `Task<byte[]>` to `sw.Write(...)`. The `ToString` is not weird at all.

Comment: it's not weird. `Console.Writeline` will simply call `(Task<string>).ToString()` and what you see is the default implementation of the `ToString()` method.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks for all! Useful as well! I feel like having a swiss-army-knife and just "knowing" how to use the big key...